# How to simply cut and paste from an editor on a remote machine to a local machine?

Tags: remote, paste

My Windows laptop uses a VirtualBoxed Linux machine to connect to a remote machine, both using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
On the remote machine I look at files using nano or less.
How do I copy part or all of a file from inside these terminal applications and then paste this text into my local machine (as a file or into a file via e.g. gedit)?
For reasons I won't go into, I can't scp from the remote machine.

Comment: Have you already tried setting "Shared clipboard" to "Bidirectional" in VM settings?

Comment: How are you connecting to the remote machine? Do you want to paste in the VM or in the host? Why aren't you connecting directly from the host? Why can't you use `scp` — there's a high chance that this is relevant?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a graphical terminal program (like xterm) you should just be able to copy text from the window like normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sshfs` to mount the remote machine as a local directory in your VM and look at, copy and edit the files on the remote machine.

The syntax used is

```
sshfs remote_user@remote_computer:/full/path/to/directory /path/to/local/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

For shared clipboard to work, be sure to install the VirtualBox Extension Pack on your local machine, and install the Guest Additions on the VM you're using.